# Why does my Laptop cheep/whimper when I scroll a large list?

Tags: audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What would make a noise in a PC on graphics operations on a passively-cooled system?](https://superuser.com/questions/149569/what-would-make-a-noise-in-a-pc-on-graphics-operations-on-a-passively-cooled-syst)

Every time i scroll (either with the scroll wheel or scroll bar), and it affects a large part of the screen, my laptop cheeps/whimpers. It's a quiet and high sound - like "tsiiii"...
It has nothing to do with the sound card nor the internal speaker (These are disabled).
I know some people that are faced with the same "issue".

Sound's weird, i know. Any ideas?

Comment: with you on that one @Arjan

Comment: (Still +1 for this very question, as the wording will make more people find it.)

Comment: I have never seen this happen myself, but I remember reading somewhere that it can be stopped by turning off power saving in the BIOS options (not really something that you would want to do on a laptop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question a few months ago, and the answer I got was that it was most likely the voltage regulators on the graphics card